# Hiding javascript exceptions in tapestry

Tags: javascript, exception, tapestry

In Tapestry I have a situation where I redirect user from Page A to Page B, where sometimes he is redirected to page C before page B was shown. This results in following javascript exceptions shown as red pop-ups like this one appearing on the page:

```
Exception invoking function Tapestry.Initializer.activate with parameters ["example"]: TypeError: $(...) is null
```

All elements listed as null are from Page B, which I don't want or intent to show. I cannot directly redirect user from Page A to Page C in this scenario.

I need a way in tapestry to handle those javascript exception by myself or hide them from appearing, or proper tapestry technique to redirect between pages without getting those errors. Currently I'm simulating user moving trough pages by launching redirecting code from @AfterRender function.

Edit: I've added relevant parts of the code below

On page one after user clicks modify I redirect him to user page

```
@InjectPage
UserDataPage userDataPage;

@OnEvent(value = EventConstants.ACTION, component = "modify")
Object onModify(Long userToEdit) {
    userDataPage.setUserId(userToEdit);
    userDataPage.setEditDetails(true);
    return userDataPage;
}
```

Since I really need to edit details UserDataPage does this:

```
@InjectPage
UserDetailsPage userDetailsPage;

@AfterRender
Object setup() {
    if(editDetails) {
        userDetailsPage.setUserId(userToEdit);
        return userDetailsPage;
    }
}
```

When UserDetailsPage loads it shows errors about components from UserDataPage that are missing(obviously, because I'm not on UserDataPage anymore). In Firebug I see that scripts contain all elemenents from both UserDataPage and UserDetailsPage. For example I have grid element on both pages, so resulting tapestry scripts refer both to grid and automatically renamed grid_0. Then the errors complain about missing grid from UserDataPage.

I cannot go directly from list of users(first page) to UserDetailsPage, as UserDetailsPage requires that redirect comes from UserDataPage. I'm not allowed to get rid of that requirement.

Comment: Always post the relevant parts of the code you're having trouble with. Verbal descriptions alone leave things vague and open to interpretation.

Comment: There you go, I hope it clears things up.

Comment: Why not return ```UserDetailsPage``` instance from page one? Why return ```UserDataPage``` and then redirect to ```UserDetailsPage``` in ```UserDataPage.setup()```? It doesn't make sense to me to redirect twice.

Comment: I cannot go directly from list of users(first page) to UserDetailsPage, as UserDetailsPage requires that redirect comes from UserDataPage. I'm not allowed to get rid of that requirement. It's not my decision, and I already tried to influence my superiors, but it's a no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper tapestry way to redirect between pages is by returning page class, page name or link from event handler.

```
public Object onActionFromMyLink() {
  return MyPage.class;
}
```

To hide tapestry client-side errors you can override javascript function `Tapestry.error`.

```
Tapestry.error = function() {
  console.log(...);
}
```

But I think the issue is in your code.

**UPD**:

The best way to do navigation in tapestry is by using [page activation context](http://tapestry.apache.org/page-navigation.html#PageNavigation-PageRenderRequests)

Comment: Overriding Tapestry.error did the job. Thank you. Also I've added code details in my question, if you're interested in what I'm doing.

Comment: Sounds like you are burying your head in the sand rather than actually fixing the error.

Comment: What do you mean by `UPD` ?!

Answer (score 0):

In the case where PageA redirects to PageB then PageB redirects to PageC, I don't think it's possible that PageB rendered (or caused any javascript exceptions). PageB will simply return a [302 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) response and the browser will go straight to PageC.

I'm guessing that PageC is missing an onPassivate() method (or the equivalent @PageActivationContext annotation) and that your activation context is being lost between requests.

http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/navigation/onactivateandonpassivate/3
http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/annotations/PageActivationContext.html